# Paper size inconsistency with PrintDialog and XPS Document Writer

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, xps

I have a piece of code looking like

```
var dlg = new PrintDialog();
myDocumentPaginator =
        new System.Windows.Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
dlg.PrintDocument(myDocumentPaginator, "Print");
```

The default printer is the XPS document writer.

The GetPage method of my DocumentPaginator looks like

```
public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
{
    var root = new ContentPresenter();
    // Fill root with content, dynamically sized using a Viewbox.
    root .Measure(PageSize);
    root .Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), PageSize));
    root .UpdateLayout();
    return new DocumentPage(root );
}
```

Now `dlg.PrintableAreaWidth` and `dlg.PrintableAreaHeight` are about 1122 and 798, which means that the XPS document writer is configured to use A4 paper, which is correct. The files generated by the printer are using te US letter format, though, which cuts off the page footer.

Is this a bug in my Paginator or in the XPS Document Writer?

Answer (score 0):

Should be a bug in the XPSDocumentWriter. Try it with .NET 3.5 and it should work. I think I have the same problem [.Net 4.5 wpf printing issue, paper size is always NorthAmericaLetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106409/net-4-5-wpf-printing-issue-paper-size-is-always-northamericaletter)